# How to get value of 'this' with nested {{#each}} in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I've got a simple list of documents that are generated with the {{#each}} iterator:

```
{{#each Teachers}}
    <td>{{FullName}}</td>
{{/each}}
```

When a user clicks on one of the teachers listed, a new page is routed to that teacher's profile page and we have access to that teacher's document with 'this' so I can say:

```
var phone = this.phoneNumber;
```

Now, within that teacher's profile page another list is generated of that teacher's students:

```
{{#each Students}}
  <td>{{FullName}}</td>
{{/each}}
```

When the user clicks on a student in that list (on that teacher's page), I'm trying to get access to the student document by using 'this' again. So if I wrote:

```
Template.TeacherTemplate.events({
  'click #student-name': function () {
    console.log(this.FullName);
}
```

I'd expect to see the student's full name in the console. But it's still referencing the teacher's full name here. How can I get the reference to the student when clicking the student list?

Answer (score 2):

Make another template for student.

```
<template name='student'>
  <td>{{FullName}}</td>
</template>
```

Then use student template in each loop.

```
{{#each Students}}
  {{> student}}
{{/each}}

Template.student.events({
  'click': function(){
    console.log(this.FullName);
  }
});
```